# using Options Framework - can "theme-textdomain" domain be changed?

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, localization

I'm using the Options Framework in a new theme. I would like to use the theme name as the domain for the localization functions such as `__()` and `esc_attr()`. But the localisation functions in the Options Framework source files have the domain set to 'theme-textdomain'.

I'd rather use the theme name as the domain. Is this possible, or I am forced to comply with Options Framework and use 'theme-textdomain'?

Naturally editing the Options Framework source files to change the domain name  would stain my soul for eternity - I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you distribute a theme or plugin you should "own"* the code. If you need the framework as part of the theme then include it as part of your theme code and make any modification you require. Use a source version control tool like git to be able to rebase your changes when a newer version of the framework is available in the unlikely event that you decide that upgrading is worth your time.

*own - not necessarily in the legal way, but in having a deep understanding and control over every line of the code.